# How do I prevent React Router's `browserHistory.listen` from calling the callback immediately?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

For example, when I do the following, the callback gets called as soon as I call `.listen()`:

```
let unlistener = ReactRouter.browserHistory.listen(route => {
    // do something when the path changes
});
```

How do I prevent this from happening? Or, how can I get the current route's path so I can compare route parameter with the current route?

I don't want to make this function just ignore the first execution because that's too hacky. There could be times where the function isn't called immediately.

Comment: You are saying the listen callback is always invoked immediately as well as in response to Route change? I find that hard to believe. And if it so, it's a bug.

Comment: I had the same problem but couldn't find a solution and ended up going the "ignore first execution" hack route (hah get it? I need more friends). Anyway would be really interested to see if there is an elegant solution to this.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `redux`, you can use `react-router-redux` (https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux). When you set it up, on each changes to the history there is a `LOCATION_CHANGE` action being dispatched.

The main advantage of adding a reducer to handle the `LOCATION_CHANGE` is that you do get the new path in the action's payload, and you have a reference to your current route in the store's `state`.

Comment: Note this is now `@@router/LOCATION_CHANGE`